# How to allow only specific user's computer to access asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to allow only specific user's computer to access asp.net web application?

Actually our data is very sensitive we can not allow anyone to access our web application to just verify UserName or Password. we can not allow user to give their username and password to others.
only registered client machine can use our web application.

- we can install a setup file on client machine.

Comment: This is not a question for C#, this is networking problem !

Comment: @mybirthname That would be one solution, you can also imagine using a client-side certificate which makes it a c#/asp.net config issue or use a different identity provider that uses tokens/sms/app which makes it a full asp.net/c# issue. The question is too broad to have a good answer.

Comment: @rene Please guide me that how can I generate different identity for every client machine? It should be unchangeable by client.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an allowrule.

1. Open the IIS-Admin-Console
2. Navigate to your website-settings which should be restricted
3. open "IPv4 Address and Domain Restrictions."
4. Add an allowrule
5. In the "add a new allowrule"-Dialog set all the settings you need.
6. It think a restart of the website or the IIS-Service should be done.

Here is a Microsoft TechNet article which describes exactly what you have to do. 
It also describes if you want to restrict requests to a specified domain.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731598(v=ws.10).aspx